How to proxy_pass external website with static content on CDN?
I have external website with landing page (Elementor), for example https://new.domain.com/landing.
But some static content (.js) doesn't load and landing web page through NGINX doesn't work properly.
How to proper configure NGINX to proxy_pass to external landing page which used remote static content from Cloudflare?
I tried to use NGINX with proxy pass like this:
    location /custom/newpage {
        proxy_pass https://new.domain.com/landing;
        proxy_set_header Host new.domain.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;


Share screen shot from network tab of your browser when static contents don't work properly.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I don't see any errors, but I'm pretty sure that some .js files aren't loading. There are 36 requests through nginx and 39 requests directly. I suspect some files are missing from the webpack initiator.

I used Cloudflare, and the issues were resolved by adding a Page Rule in the Cloudflare admin panel.
